# Implement masking algorithm ( eg: noise addition) on excel numerical data using java or python

Tags: java, python, data-masking

i would like to find an algorithm to mask numerical data given in an excel file
any suggestions on this implementations as i am stuck...i have loaded in the file but not sure where to go next for noise addition as a masking method

```
import pandas as pd

load = pd.read_excel("numericaldata.xls")
print(load)
```

any help on this Thanks

Comment: If all your data is numeric, you can just run a function over each column to change the values. Just make sure you can run the inverse of that function to get back your original data

Comment: @kynnem how do u add noise addition as a masking method? can u provide a sample for the change in value as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a simple function to an example column as follows:

```
def encrypt(data):
    encrypted = data**2 + 18
    return encrypted

def decrypt(data):
    decrypted = (data - 18) ** 0.5
    return decrypted
```

You can then run encrypt on a column of your original data and assign it to a column of a new dataframe which you can save for later. When you want to load your encrypted dataframe, just run decrypt and you get the original data.

These functions are just examples. You could use variations addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division as you like. You can even try converting the numbers to letters instead.

Comment: would that be considered adding noise to the data?

Comment: Yes it would. It's a defined noise which masks your data, but you can still retrieve the original data

Comment: and how would i plot a risk vs information loss map with the masked data

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do that